# Solicitar dato hasta que sea ingresado en Java

Tags: java, validación

Buen día a todos, es mi primer pregunta y espero hacerme entender.
Tengo un JFrame en Java en donde pido los datos de un estudiante y los voy guardando en un arreglo de estudiantes, lo primero que hago es pedirle al usuario la cantidad de estudiantes que ingresará, pero quiero que sea obligatorio ingresar una cantidad para poder continuar, el problema que tengo es que cuando le doy aceptar sin haber ingresado ningún dato la primer vez, hace lo que quiero que haga, que muestre un mensaje que informe que no se ingresaron datos y pida de nuevo la cantidad de estudiantes a ingresar, pero a la segunda vez que doy aceptar o cancelar sin ingresar datos, me lanza la excepción NumberFormatException, a continuación dejo el código:

```html
public class EstudianteGui extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    Estudiante[] arregloEstudiantes;
    int contadorEstudiantes;
    int cantEstudiantes = 0;
    int contadorCupos;

    public EstudianteGui()
    {
        initComponents();

        try
        {
            cantEstudiantes = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cantidad de estudiantes"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
//Específicamente en esta parte es donde no he podido validar que se repita
//el ciclo de pedir la cantidad de estudiantes hasta que se ingrese un dato.
            while (cantEstudiantes == 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ingresaron datos");
                cantEstudiantes = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cantidad de estudiantes"));
                if (cantEstudiantes > 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } finally
        {
            arregloEstudiantes = new Estudiante[cantEstudiantes];
            contadorEstudiantes = 0;
            contadorCupos = cantEstudiantes;
            lblCupos.setText(String.valueOf(contadorCupos));
        }
    }
```

Espero se entienda la pregunta y que soy estudiante si el código no es bueno, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, dejaré la solución por si a alguien le sirve, y también recibo opciones para optimizar el código.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente forma:

```html
public class EstudianteGui extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

    Estudiante[] arregloEstudiantes;
    int contadorEstudiantes;
    String cantEstudiantes; //cambié el tipo de int a String
    int contadorCupos;
    int cantidad; //agregué esta variable

    public EstudianteGui()
    {
        initComponents();

        try
        {
            //Dejé que esta variable reciba el valor en String.
            cantEstudiantes = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cantidad de estudiantes");
            //Y después la convertí en int.
            cantidad = Integer.parseInt(cantEstudiantes);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            //Cambié la condición indicando que si la cadena está vacía,
            //se repita el ciclo de pedir la cantidad.
            while (cantEstudiantes.isEmpty())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ingresaron datos");
                cantEstudiantes = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cantidad de estudiantes");
            }
        } finally
        {
            arregloEstudiantes = new Estudiante[cantidad];
            contadorEstudiantes = 0;
            contadorCupos = cantidad;
            lblCupos.setText(String.valueOf(contadorCupos));
        }
//        cantEstudiantes = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cantidad de estudiantes"));
//        arregloEstudiantes = new Estudiante[cantEstudiantes];
//        contadorEstudiantes = 0;
    }
```